# Use converted variable inside a regular expression python 2.6

Tags: python, regex, string

I tried many diffrent way but not success, i want to use string variable while running re.search function. But if i use a string which is converted from a list member it is not succeeded, if i define a str variable i can do, when check type of variables both of them is str.

```
mylist=['upl1', 'upl2', 'upl3']
ara_ci=mylist[2]
ara_ci=str(ara_ci)
#if i define it like this , not success

ara_ci='upl3'
#if i define it like this , success


IFAL='list_upl3_other'

if re.search(r'%s' % ara_ci, IFAL):
    CLASS='TEST'
else:
    CLASS='DEFAULT'
```

Comment: That's not even valid Python.

Answer (score 1):

`ara_ci=str(ara_ci)` is the sytax for type-casting something to `str`. Note `(..)` instead of `[..]`.

`something[i]` is the syntax for accessing `i`th index of *something* `list` OR, value of `i` key from *something* `dict`.

Also, it is not good practice to over-ride python keywords (based on *ara_ci=**list**[3]*). [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) is data-type in Python

Comment: In that case you should mention the error you are getting. It is hard to say anything without that

Comment: i edited the code, still working on it, but not succeed yet. what is difference between converted str and str , it is strange.

Comment: In your `if` you want to check whether `ara_ci` is part of `IFAL` or not. Right?

Comment: yes, and when i use converted variable member of list , it not work

Comment: @serkun: Check your code now. I think by fixing the errors I mentioned. You actually fixed your code.

Comment: @serkun: Please accept the answer if it helped for others looking for the similar solution in future :)

Comment: i think i am tired, it is still not working =( i will check it with fresh brain.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Please explain more. I verified your code, it is working.